# Identifying connections/ intersections of vectors

Tags: qgis

I would like to identify which vectors connect/ intercept within the same layer. In more detail I have 1000s of vector lines and I would like to identify which lines are connected to each other without manually clicking on each trail to identify the vector id. Is there a method that I could use that saves me time on manually doing it?

Comment: what are your datasources ? shapefiles ? postgis tables ?

Comment: The shapefiles are ESRI shapefiles and are exported in CSV file/table. If thats helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:
[Youtube answer by 
Bhaskar Reddy Pulsani](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-oZPfgP3yM)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps in the video linked to by yair suari written out:

The approach uses the `Line intersections` tool in QGIS.
In the tool GUI, select the line vector layer as both `Input layer` and `Intersect layer`, and use its unique ID field for both `Input unique ID field` and `Intersect unique ID field`. Running the tool then gives you all intersections in the line layer as a point feature.

Below is screenshot that illustrates the above steps. The lines are labeled according to the id field in the 'lines' feature.
[image]